# Why getter function don't return Result type?

Tags: pallet, rust, macro

I'm using `#[pallet::getter(fn get_balance)]` for my StorageMap to generate a getter function, but it returns pure u64 instead of Result type. What is the way to handle missing key cases then?

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn get_balance)]
    pub(super) type Balances<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, u64, ValueQuery>;
```

```
    #[pallet::weight(10_000)]
    pub fn transfer(
        _origin: OriginFor<T>,
        to: T::AccountId,
        value: u64,
    ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
        let sender = ensure_signed(_origin)?;
        let sender_balance = Self::get_balance(&sender);
        let receiver_balance = Self::get_balance(&to).ok_or(0 as u64);
```

After cargo check I receive this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `ok_or` found for type `u64` in the current scope
  --> pallets/ERC20/src/lib.rs:93:50
   |
93 |             let receiver_balance = Self::get_balance(&to).ok_or(0 as u64);
   |                                                           ^^^^^ method not found in `u64`
```

I'm using 4.0.0-dev version FRAME libraries and 5.0.0 version sp-* libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trait bound.

You are using `ValueQuery`.

The value in the storage map must be implemented `Default`.

If the key is missing in the storage map, then the default value will be returned.

If you don't want a default value, go for [`OptionQuery`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.OptionQuery.html). If you want a result, then `X::get(y).ok_or(Error)?`.